# Should I include non significant coefficient for forecasting with ARIMA model?

Tags: time-series, statistical-significance, forecasting, arima, model-selection

My goal is to make forecasts from a time series by using an ARIMA model, but I am **not sure if I should include a non-significant coefficient in my equation** for predicting future values.

I have tried some models and ended up picking an **ARIMA (2, 1, 0)** as the best one, comparing the AICs and RMSEs. However, when observing the standard errors and p-values for the hypothesis tests, I found that the coefficient of the first autoregressive component was not significant. Also, the ACF and PACF showed no effect from the first lag. So, my question is: should I **include** this term to make predictions or should it be **removed** from the equation?

Answer (score 1):

Usually econometric models are estimated with 2 purposes:

1. Make accurate prediction
2. Investigate something (test relationship between variables, describe some system etc.)

Since your goal is to forecast, you are interested in the best model in terms of predictive power. So, if model with insignificant coefficient produces better forecasts on the test sample than model without that coefficient in terms of RSME, MAPE or any other target metric you work with, I would keep insignificant coefficient in the model. You can simply calculate the difference in % between RSME of 2 models, there also exist statistical tests which check significance of difference between errors of 2 models (for instance, Diebold-Mariano test for RMSE).